# bash command in server startup

Tags: bash, server

I am trying to run a server. the command `x_server.sh` do not work for my ubuntu 14.04 but it runs when I give the command `bash x_server.sh`.

It has adviced that the products should not run as a daemon thread.
What I want to know is what exactly this **bash** command do, is it run as a daemon thread when  i do so and what are the alternative ways there for me to use to make that command **x_server.sh** work.

Comment: `./x_server.sh`. and maybe `chmod +x x_server.sh` if previous command says permission denied. you can find out what is bash in any search engine or any unix book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu the default shell is Dash, not Bash.  Presumably your `x_server.sh` script starts like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

You should change it to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

That will make it auto-select the best "bash" on the system rather than the default shell which is `dash` which has different (mostly fewer) features than `bash`.

And of course you need to do the usual `chmod +x x_server.sh` to make it executable in the first place, and run it as `./x_server.sh` unless it's in your $PATH.